# Value of type 'Firestore' has no member 'collectionGroup'

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm already using Firestore, and everything is working fine. Now I wanted to implement a collection group query, but Xcode shows that Firestore doesn't have a function like that. What I missing about this and where?

[image]

Currently I'm using 1.2.1 version via pods

[image]

Please help me, because we cannot solves problems without that.

Comment: Have you tried updating the pods to the latest version?  What you're showing right now looks pretty old.

Comment: I answered my question, luckily I found out the problem. There were two other pods which holded back the update

Comment: I love people when just marking -1 for a question, and nothing to say here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, finally found the problem why my pods did not get updated for the really fresh new versions. There were two pods which holded back the update:

[image]

I used both pods previously. When I cleared my whole pod file and just include the firebase and the store, it installed with the latest releases. Then when I copied back all the rest, cocoa pods told me the reason what's behind. Hope if someone got a problem like this, this will help.